# Ubuntu 15.10: laptop reboots after suspend

Tags: kernel, 15.10, suspend, bug-reporting

When I open the lid after suspending my laptop, the laptop **reboots** instead of waking up normally. However, this only happens when it's on battery.

This only happened today after Ubuntu performed some minor updates, I believe.

I am using Zenbook UX305 with ubuntu 15.10 and I am using kernel 4.5.0 rc6.

A while ago, I had this problem but I was using the original Ubuntu 15.10's kernel which is version 4.2. But installing kernel 4.5.0 fixed the problem until recently - which is weird.

Now I am facing the same problem. The fact that the kernel didn't change, I am lost as to what is causing it.

Cheers.

Comment: same problem with asus ux 303 ua

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the Ux305ua, had the same issue. Switching off fastboot in bios settings solved it for me.

I got the tip here
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108801